# what is OPTIONS type in request type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-verbs

I have used GET & POST ,DELETE etc. but what is this OPTIONS for?
What different does it do in the controller side?

Comment: It does nothing with Rails itself, it's all about HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those request methods are request-response between a client and server,

```
OPTIONS Returns the HTTP methods that the server supports
```

You can read more details from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)